# Why is a call to a function with and without a C style variadic parameter ambiguous?

Tags: c++

I thought that if you have a function with and without a `...` parameter, that the `...` would be only picked if there were no additional parameters past the last-named parameter.  So, I was surprised when I got an ambiguous overload error.

```
void test(char const*);
void test(char const*, ...);
//template <typename...Ts> void test(char const*, Ts...);

int main()
{
    test("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/oWfze38vP)

If I used the C++ `template` variadic rather than the C style variadic, there is no problem, but in this particular case, I actually need the C style version.  That, and I'd like to know what is causing the ambiguity.

Why isn't the 1st overload selected?  Is it not a "better" match?  Why is it a tie?

#### EDIT

In order to get around this ambiguity, I had to use the following workaround:

```
void test(char const*);
namespace detail {
  void test(char const*, ...);
}
template <typename...Ts>
void test(char const* fmt, Ts const&...args) {
  detail::test(fmt, args...);
}
```

Which to me feels a little convoluted and unnecessary, but that's the way it is I guess.

For those who say that `...` means "0 or more parameters", so does the template method.

Comment: It seems to me that the `, ...` here means "0 or more parameters"

Comment: They're both valid: if you comment out the first one it will still compile. I suppose the designers could have made the one with no optional list the automatic default, but they did not.

Comment: Even if it did, I would still think that it would be least specialized, so would pick the other one @LajosArpad

Comment: @molbdnilo, no, it still would work.

Comment: Not saying that it shouldn't take 0 or more parameters.  Saying that if there is an overload that specifically would work without the `...`, then that should take precedence.

Comment: `Even if it did, I would still think` Weeell, but it doesn't. So? It's hard to answer why something does not happen. Instead, the call is ambigous.

Comment: @KamilCuk, So what is the reason for not doing this when there is a better match present?  That is how overloading is supposed to work.  Select the best overload available.

Comment: I do not understand. Your question contains assumption, `better` is subjective, _you_ think it is better, for me, it is ambiguous, two calls match. The reason for the compiler not doing "this" is because the compiler was designed that way. The compiler was designed that way because C++ language was designed that way.

Comment: @KamilCuk agreed. And C++ language was designed that way because its designers disagreed with the premise of the question. And the reason for disagreeing with the premise, besides the obvious human choice is that there is no logical solution for the consistency problems arising if the two would be considered to be not ambiguous.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I would have thought that "better" in this context is not subjective.  One has a parameter list that contains a `...` and one doesn't.  Arkham's razor.  Take the simpler function signature.

Comment: @Adrian "better" implies a system of values. You value the declaration fitting more possible calls. But what if I would want to have a different implementation for `void test(char const*, char const*);` from the generalized declaration that you consider to be better? In that case, the generalized declaration would block me from doing it unless I perform a refactor. So, "better" is a subjective term, because any system of values deeply depend on the intentions. Which are subjective.

Comment: Sorry @LajosArpad, what is preventing from having an overloaded `void test(char const*, char const*)` signature?  That is still valid.

Comment: One could just post a citation of the Standard, here: *For the purposes of overload resolution, any argument for which there is no corresponding
parameter is considered to “match the ellipsis”* but I'm not sure that answers your question as to "why...?"

Comment: @AdrianMole because one of them means "anything" and the other means "something specific". "Something specific" will always be ambiguous with anything. If someone asks you to say "any" number and you reply "5". then your "5" will match the "any" number the asker requested.

Comment: @LajosArpad, not sure if you were directing AdrianMole or me.  But anyway, I'm just saying that if a call `test("a", "b")` is a better match to function sig `void test(char const*, char const*)`, then I would say it should follow that a call `test("a")` should be a better match to `void test(char const*)`.

Comment: @Adrian it was meant for you, sorry about the confusion. There is no such thing as a "better" match. It's either a match or not a match.

Comment: @LajosArpad No problem. My issue is that OP *seems* to be asking **why** the Standard says what it says. That's opinion-based and not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: @AdrianMole fair point, but there are objective criterias why the behavior the op would prefer would lead to self-contradictions. In CSS we have a specificity idea for selectors and that behaves like the op prefers. But those selectors are designed to find multiple items based on a pattern. Here we want to execute a single function, so ambiguity is a problem here.

Comment: @LajosArpad, I disagree, a call to a function that takes a ref to a class from an inheritance hierarchy, a better match is the one that has to traverse the tree less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#viable :

> First, to be a viable function, a candidate function shall have enough parameters to agree in number with the arguments in the list.
>
> - If there are m arguments in the list, all candidate functions having exactly m parameters are viable.

From https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#:argument_list,variable :

> The parameter-declaration-clause determines the arguments that can be
> specified, and their processing, when the function is called.
>
> [...]
>
> If the parameter-declaration-clause
> terminates with an ellipsis or a function parameter pack ([temp.variadic]), the number of arguments shall be equal to or greater than the number of parameters that do not have a default argument and are not function parameter packs.

The function `void test(char const*);` takes one argument of `char const *` and the function `void test(char const*, ...);` takes one argument of `char const*` followed by zero or more arguments. Both are viable for the overload resolution - have m=1 arguments in the list and `"hi"` is convertible to `const char *`.

From https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#general-3 :

> - Then the best viable function is selected based on the implicit conversion sequences needed to match each argument to the corresponding parameter of each viable function.
>
> If a best viable function exists and is unique, overload resolution succeeds and produces it as the result. Otherwise overload resolution fails and the invocation is ill-formed.

The conversion sequences for both functions are the same `"hi"` -> `const char *`, so none overload is best, so overload resolution fails.

Answer (score 0):

The second declaration means that you will get a `char const*` followed by any number of further parameters. The first declaration means that you will get exactly a `char const*`. So, there is an overlap between the two cases. Which method should be called when you get a single `char const*`? If the answer is "both", then we have a self-contradiction, which cannot be allowed. If the answer is "the first", then, if you remove the first, then the meaning of the second would depend on the context, which would also lead to code inconsistencies. If the answer is "the second", then we reach to a similar problem.

As we can see, no logical solution is possible as a result of the premise that the two are not ambiguous. Therefore: the two are ambiguous.